# split column names with grid table

Tags: r, datagrid

I want to generate formatted tables witt `grid.table`. that is what i've made:

```
library(grid)
d <- head(iris, 3)
colnames(d) <- c("A very long colname", "Sepal Width",  "Petal Length", "Petal Width",  "Species")
grid.table(d, rows=NULL,theme=ttheme_minimal(
  colhead=list(fg_params=list(col="white",fontface=4L),
               bg_params=list(fill="#1bb600"))
))
```

[image]

that is the desired result (the name column splited in two lines):

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must rename rows specifying the part in which you want to split the names with an `\n` between the parts:

```
library(grid)
d <- head(iris, 3)
colnames(d) <- c("A very\nlong colname", "Sepal\nWidth",  "Petal\nLength", "Petal\nWidth",  "Species")
grid.table(d, rows=NULL,theme=ttheme_minimal(
  colhead=list(fg_params=list(col="white",fontface=4L),
               bg_params=list(fill="#1bb600")), 
  core
))
```

[image]